# django-heroku installation giving an error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku but after executing **pip install django-heroku** it gives me an error. I'm running Python 3 with Django 2.2 on a mac.

The error message recommended to install **psycopg2-binary**, which I did but after the installation I still see the same error. Thank you for help.

**The error message:**

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6z/cqmvjcds4_s2pz_8zb28s_v40000gn/T/pip-install-28adny1a/psycopg2/
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

`sudo apt install libpq-dev`

And then run `pip install django-heroku`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Installing this package worked for me 'libpqxx' (or this one 'libpq-dev' as referred from [here](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/issues/48)!

note: im using linux so it may be different for you